# Not allowing CSS to be carried to previous page (after clicking browser back button)

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

My webapp is running into the issue of CSS being carried back to the original page when a user clicks the back button in the browser.

Here's my original page:
[image]

Here's an outside page I link to in the navigation:
[image]

Here's what happens after I click the back button (notice the heading and background color):
[image]

I tried to solve this by using `<body onload="document.refresh();">` based on a stackoverflow suggestion but it didn't solve my issue.

I'm using the Ruby on Rails framework, if that helps at all.

Comment: Are you using Turbolink (check our Gemfile)? You may want to disable it.

Comment: Thanks so much!! That worked perfectly! Would you like to put that as an answer - I will accept it so this question can be closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Turbolink (check out your Gemfile, it's a default gem in Rails 4)?
You may want to disable it.